# mongoose populate works locally but not on aws

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongoose-populate

The user model is a bit weird i know. The initial data that should be populated comes from a seed file if that makes any difference. Again, this all works locally though. None of them populate on AWS but all do locally.

````
  User
    .findById(req.params.id)
    .populate([{
      path: 'agentData.players',
      model: 'User',
      populate: {
        path: 'playerData.currentClub',
        model: 'Club'
      }
    }])
    .populate([{
      path: 'transfers',
      model: 'Transfer',
      populate: [{
        path: 'player',
        model: 'User'
      },
      {
        path: 'from',
        model: 'Club'
      },
      {
        path: 'to',
        model: 'Club'
      }]
    }])
    .populate([{
      path: 'playerData.currentClub',
      model: 'Club'
    }])
    .populate([{
      path: 'officialData.currentClub',
      model: 'Club'
    }])
    .then(user => res.status(200).json(user))
    .catch(err => res.json(err))
}```
````

Comment: may be mongoose or node versions locally are not the same as on AWS, could you check that?

Comment: That was it! mongoose and express were the same but node was 2 versions behind the latest on the EC2 instance. Thanks you so much! getting to grips with AWS and i obviously was thinking about the basics haha

Answer (score 0):

Updating the node version on the EC2 instance worked.